# What do you call a point-by-point (like Slack's) registration ui?

Tags: usability, design-patterns, terminology, registration

Slack has an effective registration that prompts the user for each data point on a different view. I've found the pattern is very nice in terms of reducing the user's cognitive load. I'm curious if there is a name for this pattern?

I've been referring to it as point-by-point registration and I'd love to know if there is a proper term (or better ideas if there is none).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material Design calls them Steppers and now I do too.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/steppers.html

Comment: It was always falled "step", way before Material Design and Slack existed

Comment: I did not and do not dispute that @devin. It is a very sensible name.

Comment: We've started calling them steppers too. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard/used
**Progressive registration**
**Phased registration**
**Just-in-time data collection**

Fundamentally, it's a **progressive disclosure** strategy for gathering information from the user.

Comment: I like these options and I also feel like they are more broad concepts than the specific UI pattern I'm referring to.

Comment: Generally speaking, I like to speak generally. I find it freeing to think in terms of fundamental strategies and avoid too much influence from other people's tactics.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing the concept of progressive disclosure. I've used it as a compliance mechanism ever since.